# TypeLoadException on LoadApplication(new App())

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, typeloadexception

I have a cross platform Xamarin Forms project which **works fine** when ran on Android or Windows Mobile.

Now I need to run it on iOS but I get an exception when the application is launched on an iPhone emulator:

"System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'XamarinMO.Services.DataServices' from assembly 'XamarinMO, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'."

The exception occurs early in the code , in the iOS AppDelegate on **LoadApplication(new App());:**

```
public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
{

    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();

        LoadApplication(new App()); -- <<*** EXCEPTION THROWN HERE ***

        ServicePointManager
        .ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
        (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }
```

I am unable to use the debugger to step into the code and the stack trace is as helpful as a chocolate kettle.

The exception does not seem to be related to the code inside my DataServices class as the execution does not even progress that far. My DataServices class seem not to even be instantiated - when I put a break point on the first line in DataServices constructor, the execution does not even get there. This indicates to me the issue is not related to the code inside the class per se (which works fine across a wide range of Android and Windows Mobile devices)

Comment: Is your Linker behaviour set to Link All?

Comment: >> "Is your Linker behaviour set to Link All"

Yes.

Comment: Try setting it to Link Sdk Assemblies only and see if this will make a difference.

Comment: @Milen. I tried that already.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause.

I had to swap the System.Net.Http in the PCL with Microsoft.Net.Http. Apparently standard .NET System.Net.Http works fine with Android or WinPhone but not iOS.

Now the projects runs fine on all platforms.